# How to get all optgroup options values and push them to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown that contains 2 optgroup inside it ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zar5bkd7/)). What I'm trying to do now is, I want to grab all options values inside the `Around The World Kitchens` optgroup and push each of the value into an array.

I'm targeting the element using `$('#daily_order_kitchen_id optgroup option')` but it's not working for me.

This is the result I'm expecting:

```
["11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
```

HTML:

```
<select id="daily_order_kitchen_id" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Default Kitchen">
        <option selected="selected" value="8">Ondricka LLC</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Around The World Kitchens">
        <option value="11">Erdman and Sons</option>
        <option value="12">Franecki, Ryan and Homenick</option>
        <option value="13">Jacobi-Sawayn</option>
        <option value="14">Toy, Hane and Zboncak</option>
        <option value="15">Bauch, Dach and Kihn</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var selectedKitchen = $("#daily_order_kitchen_id option:selected").val();
var arr = [];
$('#daily_order_kitchen_id optgroup option').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val())
});
console.log(selectedKitchen);
console.log(arr);
```

What should I do?

Comment: The issue is on your selector  `$('#daily_order_kitchen_id optgroup option')` is looking at all optgroup options including the "Default Kitchen" One.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `select` has two `optgourp` one is `Default Kitchen` and another is `Around The World Kitchens`.

If you run selector only on `optgourp` it'll take both group in consideration.

If you wanna get value from `Around The World Kitchens` , you have mention it specificly

Like this

```
optgroup[label="Around The World Kitchens"]
```

This will try to find optgroup with label `Around The World Kitchens`

Try like this

```
$('#daily_order_kitchen_id optgroup[label="Around The World Kitchens"] option').each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).val())
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/zar5bkd7/2/)**

Comment: Ok, now it's working. Would you mind to explain a little bit what you have done here and update your answer before I accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Try This code.

```
 var selectedKitchen = $("#daily_order_kitchen_id option:selected").val();
    var arr = [];
    $('#daily_order_kitchen_id option').each(function () {
        if($(this).parent().attr('label') != 'Around The World Kitchens') {
                arr.push($(this).val());    
        }       
    });
    console.log(selectedKitchen);
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Still getting this `["8", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]`

Comment: See my edit. Just check if it's parent is a part of that opt group and if so dont add it.